# Android Simple Canvas Program

Tags: android, canvas, updating

Okay, I'm trying to create a simple app that will draw a shape (I'm trying a circle) wherever you click.  I have tried a couple times, but haven't gotten anything to work yet.  I would think that somebody has done this before, so if theres a link to a tutorial/source code of a similar project, that would help. What I think I'm stuck on is how to use threads, and how to update the onDraw() function.  If you haven't figured it out already, I'm pretty new to Android and even java.

Currently I have:

--Main.java--

```
    public class MAIN extends Activity {
        CustomDrawableView mCustomDrawableView; 
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mCustomDrawableView = new CustomDrawableView(this);        
            setContentView(mCustomDrawableView);

        }

//Implement a thread here that would somehow update the view everytime.  Everytime I try this though it doesn't work
    }
```

--CustomDrawableView.java--

```
public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
    //private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;

    public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 5, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly create a thread for something this simple.

In your View, simply override onTouchEvent, switch on the MotionEvent.getAction, when it's ACTION_DOWN, set the x and y to MotionEvent.getX() and getY(), and call invalidate()

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still slightly confused.  I understand why that would work, but I'm not too sure what ___.invalidate() should be.  Should it be CustomDrawableView.invalidate()? That causes error though.

Comment: Actually I have now gotten it to work (you have to put it in Main, not the View) but everywhere i click, the circle will be placed about 20px below where I actually clicked.  Any Ideas?

Comment: onDraw gets called by the base class when you call invalidate().  I think the 20px offset is because you're doing it in the Activity class and not the View.  If your View has margins and/or padding on it, then x and y in your Activity are this many pixels off in your View.You actually don't have to override onTouchEvent in MAIN, as View (base class of your CustomDrawableView) also implements this method

Comment: AH, thanks so much! The docs and sample codes make easy things like this seem scary and nearly impossible XD.